# With Rust Polars, is there a good way to replace a specified value in a series like fill_null?

Tags: rust-polars

I have a dataset where null/missing values are represented by 0. So I'd like to do something like c.replace_val(0, "forward"). What is a good/easy/efficient way to do that?  Thanks.

Comment: are you reading from a file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. if you are reading from a file
   you can specify [your null_values](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.read_csv.html)
   and then use a `.forward_fill()` in one pass:

   d = pl.read_csv('file.csv', null_values=0)

   d.a.fill_null('forward')

2. if your are not reading from a file,
   I am afraid you need to impute your 0s first and then replace them.
   You can chain `when/then/otherwise/fill_null`. E.g.,

   d.with_column(
   pl.when(col("a") == 0)
   .then(None)
   .otherwise(col("a"))
   .fill_null("forward")